# MSBUILD .NET Core solution not setting the product version over the command line

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, msbuild

I am currently setting the AssemblyVersion over the command line:

```
& $msbuild "D:\Jenkins\workspace\Snarks\KPS.MAX graphics\KPS.MAX graphics - Compile\MainProj.sln" -r -m:7 -t:Build "-property:Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU;AssemblyVersion=1.0.33.174"
```

In the project file i have the following prebuild event:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Updating AssemblyInfo to Version $(AssemblyVersion)"></Message>
    <Message Text="Writing to AssemblyInfo files in $(SolutionRoot)"></Message>
    <AssemblyInfo AssemblyInfoFiles="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" 
                  AssemblyCopyright="$(AssemblyCopyright)" 
                  AssemblyVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"
                  AssemblyFileVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"
                  >
    </AssemblyInfo>
</Target>
```

The result is that the assembly has the version 1.0.33.174 but the file version is just 1.0.0.0:

[image: Assembly Properties]

I'm not sure why AssemblyFileVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)" isn't setting the relevant property, can anyone help here?

Comment: Where is this `AssemblyInfo` task coming from?

Comment: The standard [MSBuild tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task-reference?view=vs-2022) don't include an `AssemblyInfo` task. Is this a custom task someone in your organization wrote?

Comment: Is this an SDK style project or a legacy style project? SDK style projects support [MSBuild properties for setting the assembly info attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes-project-file). If your project is an SDK style project, delete your custom `BeforeBuild` target.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanDodds, it is an SDK-style project and the customer BeforeBuild target was preventing the FileVersion & InformationalVersion being set by the MSBuild properties.